# How does this function return its value?

Tags: function, powershell

I'm actually scripting and a part of my script is a FTP file download. The code words without any problem, but I don't understand one specific part. Its the only part from the code I haven't written by myself. I understand how the code works, but I actually dont understand how the function return its value. You're may confused what I mean, so let me explain it with a bit of code:

```
function get-ftp {

    try {

        $ftprequest = [system.net.ftpwebrequest]::Create($uri)
        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object system.net.networkcredential($user,$pass)
        $ftprequest.Proxy = $null
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
        $ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()
        $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $ftpresponse.GetResponseStream() 
        $reader.ReadToEnd()
        $reader.Close()
        $ftpresponse.Close()

    }

    catch {

        Write-host "Error while reading filenames"

    }
}
```

So this is my function to get all directories from the FTP server. I call this function with this code:

```
$allXmlFiles = get-ftp
```

So after the call, my `$allXmlFiles` contains a string (tested with `getType` on `$allXmlFiles`) with all the filenames on the server. Now my question: How is the answer from the FTP passed to this variable? There's no `return` in the function, so I'm quite confused how this works. I tried so take the `try/catch` out of the function and access the answer directly, but that didin't work. I tried to find it in `$reader` and in `$ftpresponse` - no success.

It would be really cool if someone can explain me whats going on here. As said, the code works, but I would like to understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

```
$reader.ReadToEnd()
```

[StreamReader.ReadToEnd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method outputs string and since it's result is not assigned to variable it will be the function output.

Idiomatic way would be to write it like this:

```
Write-Output $reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell, the result of every command / statement is returned as output if you don't *assign* or *pipe* it to anything. 
The **return** keyword only exits the current scope. You rarely use `return` in PowerShell.

As beatcracker mentioned, `$reader.ReadToEnd()` is producing the output.